# How to repeat a song by Soundcloud API

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundcloud, repeat

I am making a custom music player based on SoundCloud API. I want to have a repeat button so when it is pressed, the current song will be repeated.  SoundCloud does not provide any repeat method as far as I know, but it has some `position()` methods that get the corrent position of the song. I could not make this method working. But do you have any suggestion for repeating the current stream song ?

my code so far:

```
function playIt(){
var sound = SC.stream("/tracks/293", function(sound){
    sound.play();
    
});
}
function repeat(){
    var sound = SC.stream("/tracks/293", function(sound){
    console.log(sound.position);
    });
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/danials/zcN7G/23/

Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a much shorter track in your jsfiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var repeatSong = function() {
    this.play({onfinish: repeat});
};

var sound = SC.stream("/tracks/293", function(sound){
    sound.play({onfinish: repeatSong});        
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G5RdX/1/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried to run it but did not work. Can you show it on JSFiddle please. Thanks

Comment: Wow perfect. I just have a question, is this onfinish option is a SoundCloud feature ? I am just trying to figure out what you did.

Comment: Yes. onFinish is an event for SoundManager2 play api. Take a look at this: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/. This event fires when play finishes. I just scripted it to keep calling play every time play finishes